# How to perform a page navigation action for a button which is in the Application.Resource?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I put several ApplicationBars in  in the App.xaml because I want to display different ApplicationBar for different pivot pages. However, how do I perform an navigation action using the ApplicationBarIconButton? Because when I put the Navigation code in App.xaml.cs. Visual Studio gives me an error which says "An object reference is required for non-static field, method or property "System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)".

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the app's frame's `NavigationService` instance.

> (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate();

Comment: Actually, I used RootFrame.Navigate().